# Logging the procedure and query which deleted the data from table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to find out the procedure which is deleting data from one of the table in my database. I want to put a trigger on this table which will log the name of procedure and query which is deleting the data.
Could someone please suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dbms_utility.format_call_stack` function inside the trigger to retrieve information about which procedure has issued the delete. See the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_util.htm#ARPLS73240) - not too much info, but the usage is pretty straightforward (no arguments). Also take note of other useful functions like `format_error_backtrace`.

In 12c you also have [utl_call_stack](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2013/06/12c-utlcallstack.html).